# About a kind of "split" genitive

Tags: morphology

> Der englische Text **des** von Dr. H. Kesting übersetzten und vom Verfasser **neu durchgesehen Buches** erschien 1949 beim Verlag der Chicago Universität unter dem Titel *Meaning in History*.

(Karl Löwith, *Weltgeschichte und Heilsgeschehen: Die theologischen Voraussetzungen der Geschichtsphilosophie*)

In a "normal" word order, this would have been, I think:

> Der englische Text des neu durchgesehen Buches [...]

```
(The English text of the newly revised book...)
```

Why is the definite article of the noun *Buch*, in the genitive case, *des*, separated off from its corresponding noun, *Buches*, also in the genitive case, like this?

I have never seen such a "split" genitive construction, if you will. What grammatical phenomenon does it represent?

Comment: Because you want to include multiple pieces of information about the book, that it has been translated by Dr. H. Kesting and that it was recently reviewed. So actually the normal word order, without the additional information would be: Der englische Text des übersetzten und neu durchgesehenen Buches, but there is also a lot of information relating to the translation and the review, which results in the long split. There is no deep grammatical structure present except for the position of the declined adjectives (übersetzt, durchgesehen) and the positions of the information regarding those.

Comment: Where else would you put the article?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the genitive. It is just an example of the general principle that when you take a grammatical sentence and replace one part of speech by an equivalent one, you normally get another grammatical sentence. This is true in German to a greater extent than it is in English. Let's start with a simplified form of the subject of your example sentence:

> Der Text des Buches (The text of the book)

As you know, you may add an adjective to the noun *Buch*, which then ends up between the definite article and the noun. (Technically, in German, participles are generally not considered to *be* adjectives; they just *behave like* adjectives in sentences most of the time. But let's ignore that and call *durchgesehen* an adjective for now.) This is what we get:

> Der Text des durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the revised book)

This is because a noun may be replaced by a noun qualified by an adjective (or participle). As you already know, you may add an adverb in front of the participle *durchgesehen*:

> Der Text des neu durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the newly revised book)

This is because an adjective may be replaced by an adjective qualified by an adverb. But there are also other, more complicated ways of qualifying an adjective. In particular, since the 'adjective' *durchgesehen* is actually the past participle of the transitive verb *(etwas) durchsehen*, one way to qualify it is to supply the subject of the verb, i.e. the person who did the revising. We do this by using one of the prepositions *von* and *durch*, which in this connection correspond to English *by*. (The choice between the two is basically free, although often one of them is preferred because the other would be ambiguous.) Thus we get the following:

> Der Text des vom Verfasser durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the book revised by the author)

As you can see, German follows the general principle that qualifications to an adjective appear *before* the adjective. In English, they sometimes occur before (like *newly*), and sometimes after the adjective (like *by the author*).

Note: In this case this results in an ambiguity that is present only in the English version: Is it the book that was revised by the author, or is it only the text? If an important error in the cover was fixed, the difference may be important to the author. But I am sure one can also find examples where the German system results in ambiguity that doesn't arise in English.

Since a qualified adjective behaves very much like an adjective, we can also qualify it again. Thus we can qualify *neu durchgesehenes Buch* by *vom Verfasser*:

> Der Text des vom Verfasser neu durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the book newly revised by the author)

Or we can qualify *vom Verfasser durchgesehenes Buch* by *neu*:

> Der Text des neu vom Verfasser durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the book newly revised by the author)

Here we see one aspect in which German grammar genuinely creates less ambiguity. If you add some qualifications before a word and some after it, you will never be able to clarify the hierarchy between them through their order. This is why the last two English translations are identical even though the German sentences express slightly different ideas. The version *vom Verfasser neu durchgesehen* just implies that someone revised the book, and that it was the author who did it. In the version *neu vom Verfasser durchgesehen*, however, *neu (newly)* would qualify the entire phrase *vom Verfasser durchgesehen* and therefore would imply that the author has done it at least once before.

(Note that the following slight difference in meaning between *durchsehen* and *revise* becomes relevant here. While *durchsehen* literally translates to *look through* (or *peruse*), *revise* has a strong implication of looking at something **again**. Therefore one is more likely to include editorial work done before the first publication in *durchsehen* than one is to include it in *revise*. Consequently, the most likely meaning of *neu vom Verfasser durchgesehen* is that the author did this work him-/herself for the first edition and has now done it again. There is no suggestion that we are talking about at least the third edition and that the author has already done another post-publication revision before.)

It is also possible to combine two qualifications of an adjective using *und*:

> Der Text des übersetzten und durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the translated and revised book)

This also applies to more complicated qualifications:

> Der Text des von Kesting übersetzten und vom Verfasser durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the book translated by Kesting and revised by the author)

Or even more complicated qualifications:

> Der Text des von Dr. H. Kesting übersetzten und vom Verfasser neu durchgesehenen Buches (The text of the book translated by Dr H. Kesting and newly revised by the author)

With almost no bounds on how complicated the qualifications may get:

> Der Text des mit der von ihm gewohnten Sorgfalt durch Dr. H. Kesting übersetzten und trotz widriger Umstände vom Verfasser neu durchgesehenen Buches ... (Literal translation: "The text of the - with the for him usual accuracy - by Dr H. Kesting translated, and - despite adverse conditions - by the author newly revised, book ..."; proper translation: "The book was translated by Dr H. Kesting with his usual accuracy and newly revised by the author despite adverse conditions. The text of the book ...")

This is an example of a typical problem that arises when translating from German to English. Just as in translations from Latin, you very often have to split a long German sentence into several shorter English sentences. (In this last example I replaced "von Dr. H. Kesting" by "durch Dr. H. Kesting" because this prevents the sequence of words "Sorgfalt von", which is not a phrase but could erroneously be taken for one, leading to a failure to parse the sentence correctly.)

Comment: When I posted this question earlier, I didn't even imagine I would learn so much from the answers that I did get for it. Unfortunately, participial adjectives are only superficially dealt with in your average grammars of German... By the way, you are an excellent explainer.

Answer (score 2):

This is in no way specific to the genitive.

The definite article to a substantive is placed before any adjectives or other constructs that further qualify the substantive.

> das dicke Buch
>
> das neu durchgesehene Buch [nom, acc]
>
> des neu durchgesehene Buches [gen]
>
> dem neu durchgesehenen Buch [dat]

Once you start adding further qualifications to the substantive, the bracket between definitive article and substantive opens even wider.

> das neu durchgesehene, von Hans Müller geschriebene, von Fritz Maier illustrierte und im Verlag Schultze erschienene, dicke, grüne Buch.

Comment: And it is also the same if you replace "neu durchgesehen" by a simple adjective.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked why is _des_ separated from its corresponding noun, _Buches_. I thought I was clear enough in my question.

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 I guess what you asked is why there is so much text between the article and the substantive. And I answered that everything between the article and the substantive *is further qualifying* the substantive. In case you asked something different, please clarify.

Comment: Well, that's how you do this: Der Schwanz **des** [gestern erst gestriegelten, schön anzusehenden, wohlerzogenen, gutmütigen, nach meinem Dafürhalten vorbildlich abgerichteten] **Hundes** hat  die Ming-Vase gestreift.*

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, in your sentence, why does "corresponding" separate "its" from "noun"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you may be misunderstanding parts of the sentence. In particular, you may be confused by the function of "von". It is not a possessive, but corresponds to the English "by" in a passive construction.

So let us start with the essential parts.

> Der englische Text des Buches erschien [...]

should not present any problem. You also seem to be ok with

> Der englische Text des neu durchgesehen Buches erschien [...]

Now who did this revision? The book has been revised by the author. It is a book revised by the author, "vom Verfasser neu durchgesehen". In German, this qualification of "neu durchgesehen" is easily added to "neu durchgesehen":

> Der englische Text des vom Verfasser neu durchgesehen Buches erschien [...]

That you cannot do that as easily in English is a problem of that language, not of the German language.

In the same way, the book has been translated by Dr. H. Kesting. *Es ist ein von Dr. H. Kesting übersetztes Buch.*

> Der englische Text des von Dr. H. Kesting übersetzten Buches erschien [...]

But actually, the book is both "von Dr. H. Kesting übersetzt" and "vom Verfasser neu durchgesehen", so you get the original sentence.

Comment: I know what _von_ means. Hence my confusion when I read _des von_. And one more thing: in the quoted sentence it's _übersetzten_, not the past participle _übersetzt_. And this is just one more source for my original confusion.

Comment: *des rot**en** Buches*, *das Buch ist rot*. Same with *übersetzt**en***, *übersetzt*.

Comment: You should not read *des von*. You should read *des*, keep that somewhere in your mind, then read *von Dr. H. Kesting übersetzten* and later recall the *des*.

Comment: In English I can say *the book, which is red* or, easier, *the red book*. I can say *the book, which has been translated by Dr. H. Kesting*, but I **cannot** say *the by Dr. H. Kesting translated book* (and also **not** *the translated by Dr. H. Kesting* book, even though I can say *the book, translated by Dr. H. Kesting*). Well, in German I can.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. And _übersetzten_ (übersetzt + en) is an adjectival participle, right?

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, you tell me, I am just a native speaker, not a grammarian :)

Comment: Well, with that _-en_ at the end of it, it definitely is an adjectival participle. I know my grammar, theoretically, but it's still not firmly embedded in my pate. Hence my reading a lot in German. Practice is everything. Anyway, I do appreciate your effort and patience to explain all this to me. Danke!

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, actually I may have been a bit impatient at first until I got a better idea what your problem might be. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist im Englischen doch auch nicht anders:

> The tail of **the** beautiful, well-trained and principally very cautious **dog** almost toppled the expensive Chinese vase.

Was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: The difference lies in this: _des von_.

Comment: Still I do not see a difference. English does not have (any more) flective forms of "the". *The [beautiful, well-trained] dog's tail almost toppled the vase* is quite a parallel construction to your German sentence, isn't it?