# "The German that I write"

Tags: participle

Based on what I learned from the answers I got to [my previous question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37947/about-a-kind-of-split-genitive), I wrote on a German site

> Mein schreibendes Deutsch

to translate into English the sentence in the title:

> The German that I write.

But a native speaker, not knowing what I am trying to find out, corrected my original sentence into

> Mein schriftliches Deutsch.

But this actually means

> My written [recorded] German.

So it's not the same as

> The German that I write.

Having said all that, is my original sentence, *Mein schreibendes Deutsch*, correct, especially in light of the grammatical knowledge that I got from the answers to my previous question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Mein schreibendes Deutsch" translates to "My German that writes". Not what you are looking for.

"Mein schriftliches Deutsch" actually *can* be translated with "The German that I write".. in the sense of "The German that I am able to write".

If you want to translate "The German that I write right now" instead, the closest possibility using an attribute is "Mein geschriebenes Deutsch". It both means the same as "Mein schriftliches Deutsch" (general capability) as well as "The German that I wrote a few moments ago".

However, to truly capture the present-ness of the English translation.. just translate literally: "Das Deutsch, das ich (gerade) schreibe".

Comment: But _Mein geschriebenes Deutsch_ actually means "My _written_ German," right?

Comment: Yes. But from a philosophical point of view, the action of writing a word is already in the past as soon as you begin writing the next one, so you can use it in pretty much the same context as "the German that I write right now". If you want to focus a bit more on what you are about to write in the next moments, you can say "Mein zu schreibendes Deutsch" ("The German that I have to write now" ("have to" ~> "I tasked myself to")).

Answer (score 3):

> Mein schriftliches Deutsch

is indeed the way to go, it refers to the current quality of your German if you write it.

If you want to address your recorded German you could say

> Mein [bisher] geschriebenes Deutsch

*»Mein schreibendes Deutsch«* is wrong since a language does not write itself.